# get list of all contract on bybit

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, ccxt, bybit

i want to fetch all future contract on bybit
so i am using ccxt i use exchange.loadmarkets()
which give data

```
data = {'BTC/USDT': {'id': 'BTCUSDT',
  'symbol': 'BTC/USDT'},
 'ETH/USDT': {'id': 'ETHUSDT',
  'symbol': 'ETH/USDT'},
 'XRP/USDT': {'id': 'XRPUSDT',
  'symbol': 'XRP/USDT'}}
```

when i visialize by converting it to dataframe it give following

```
pd.DataFrame(data)

        BTC/USDT    ETH/USDT    XRP/USDT
id      BTCUSDT     ETHUSDT     XRPUSDT
symbol  BTC/USDT    ETH/USDT    XRP/USDT
```

How can i get like id => BTCUSDT, ETHUSDT,XRPUSDT
like this

pls help :)

Comment: You have to better explain what you want, maybe pd.DataFrame(data).loc['id'].tolist()`?

Comment: Totally unclear what you want. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the "id" values?

```
out = pd.DataFrame(data).loc['id'].tolist()
```

Or, without pandas, which is likely more efficient:

```
out = [d['id'] for d in data.values()]
```

Output: `['BTCUSDT', 'ETHUSDT', 'XRPUSDT']`

Or, for fun:

```
from operator import itemgetter

out = list(map(itemgetter('id'), data.values()))
```